# Check regular expressions php

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have a string with a number of 'shortcodes' in thus (just using an example):

```
$str = "[video src="http://www.aaa..." options="autoplay controls loop mute"]\n
        [video src=" http://www.bbb..." options="autoplay controls loop mute"]";
```

I'm trying to match each one independantly using preg_match() thus:

```
pregmatch( '/\[video.*\]/', $str, $matches );
```

Now I expect `count($matches);` to return '2'. But I only get 1 each time. Is my regular expression wrong? I need to assaign each `[video ...... ]` to a new array item so I can deal with them individually.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `preg_match_all`:

```
preg_match_all( '/\[video.*\]/', $str, $matches );
```

[See it](http://www.ideone.com/2YLY5)

Comment: Ah, I see. thanks. Why does it nest each match in array(1). I was expecting to see array(2) on it's own. If I was to perform a count on that array, I'd still only get one variable, wouldn't I?